# jQuery validate errorPlacement removal

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Im having difficulty removing the error from the area assigned by the errorPlacement once field is validated. Any help is really appreciated!

```
$('document').ready(function(){
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
       a: {required:true, minlength:2}
    },      
    messages: {
       a: {required: "enter your name!"}       
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     if(element.attr('name') == 'a'){
         error.appendTo($('#restErrorDate'));                    
     }
    },
    success: function(error){

    },
    debug:true
});
$('#a').blur(function(){
    $("form").validate().element("#a");
});
});
```

Here is the html:

```
<div>
<form action="#" id='commentForm'>
    <input type="text" name="a" id="a">
</form>
</div>
<div id="restErrorDate" class="restErrorDate" style="border:1px solid blue;"></div>
```

and here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/mmw562/Evxd9/

Comment: You do not need the whole `$('#a').blur()` function.  [**By default**, validation occurs on blur (`onfocusout`)](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions).   See:  http://jsfiddle.net/Evxd9/3/

Comment: @Sparky672: Doesn't work for me. I thought that was strange too, but I guess it's the OP's decision to have the validation run on blur.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: See [http://jsfiddle.net/Evxd9/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/Evxd9/3/).  Enter 1 character and click anywhere outside of field to trigger blur event... working fine for me.

Comment: Yes, you have to enter a character. With the OP's code you do not, just focus/blur triggers validation. (click/tab into the input, enter nothing, then click/tab elsewhere)

Comment: @WesleyMurch, I see what you mean.  It's just the first initialization that's different then.  After you enter that first character, just focus/blur triggers validation no matter what else you do, even if you delete all characters from field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of appending (which will keep adding more), just overwrite all the existing HTML:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if(element.attr('name') == 'a'){
        // error.appendTo($('#restErrorDate'));
        $('#restErrorDate').html(error);                
    }
},
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Evxd9/2/